# DropZone JS not grabbing external value from input field called by jQuery ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I am experiencing an issue with DropZone JS Grabbing an `input` value and passing it along to the upload script.  The upload is working and everything is fine EXCEPT this field not sending in the `POST`.

I have a very basic DZ config:

```
$("#file_uploader").dropzone({
    url: '/ajax/upload.php',
    dictDefaultMessage: 'Drop photos or click here to upload',
    maxFilesize: 400000,
    params: {'project': $('#project-name').val()}, // This is the part I am having issues with
    success: function (file, response) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        if (obj.status === 'success') {
            console.log('gtg');
        } else {
            alert('upload failed');
            $(".dz-preview").remove();
        }
    }
});
```

I have a field in my `html` that looks like:

```
 <input type="text" id="project-name" required="required"
       class="form-control col-md-6 col-xs-12 limited_form"
       placeholder="Project Name">
```

If I simply overwrite `'project': $('#project-name').val()` to look like:

```
'project': 'test'
```

It works.  So it's a matter of Dropzone not being able to "see" that input field for some reason.

I thought it might be the dash in the id `project-name` -- But according to the rules in HTML5 dashes are allowed in Ids.

There are no errors in the console, and this:

```
// Testing if Selector is working
$(document).on('keyup', '#project-name', function () {
    console.log( $('#project-name').val() );
});
```

displays the `project-name` contents in the console correctly as I type them, so I know my selector is OK. Thus, my confusion on why DropZone isn't "seeing" it.

Why is DropZone "ignoring" my jQuery identified by selector id? Am I missing something glaringly wrong?

**UPDATE**
It is worth noting that my config lies within a `$(document).ready(function () {` -- However I have tried it both inside, and outside the function and still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Your dropzone script was probably trying to retrieve the value before the element is loaded on the DOM. Loading your script inside a `$( document ).ready()` function would be one way to go about it. Another way would be to just assign the script to a variable and then referencing the variable in dropzone like this:

```
$("#file_uploader").dropzone({
    url: '/ajax/upload.php',
    dictDefaultMessage: 'Drop photos or click here to upload',
    maxFilesize: 400000,
    params: {'project': function() {
      var x = $('#project-name').val();
      return x;
    }},
    success: /* some function */
});
```

---

You can also try to directly return the input value within the function and see if that works.

```
$("#file_uploader").dropzone({
    url: '/ajax/upload.php',
    dictDefaultMessage: 'Drop photos or click here to upload',
    maxFilesize: 400000,
    params: {'project': function() {
      return $('#project-name').val();
    }},
    success: /* some function */
});
```

Comment: Do let me know if this approach works or not so I can modify or delete it if it doesn't. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks .. I'll be getting back to that script shortly .. What you are saying makes sense ..  I do know that `(document).ready()` makes no difference .. But having a function inside the DZ makes total sense .. I'll be sure to update when I get back to it .. Thanks!

Comment: Neither work .. They just send through the **literal** text --> `function() { return $('#project-name').val(); }` as `post` for variable `project` to `upload.php`